# I want to print a pattern of ones and zeroes

Tags: c++

for n=5 the desired output is :-

1

01

010

1010

10101

But this code prints only the first 1 one and all other ones are printed as zeroes.

```
int n;
cin>>n;
int c=1;
for(int i=1;i<=n;i++)
{
  for(int j=1;j<=i;j++)
  {
      cout<<c;
      if(c=1)
      {
          c=0
      }
      else{
        c=1
      }
    

  }
  cout<<endl;
}
return 0;
```

}

Comment: You are using assignment in a condition. `if(c = 1)` will always return true (since assignment returns the assigned value, 1, which is interpreted as `true`), I think you want `if(c == 1)`? So essentially, the first time `cout<<c` hits, `c` is 1, but then it is reset to 0 in every iteration. Then it is printed and set to 1 and then 0 again.. over and over again.

Comment: Oh I just realized, such a silly mistake. Thanks man ..

Answer (score 1):

one practice I prefer is to keep the constants/magic number on the left side of the condition expression so if by mistake I use an assignment operator, the compiler will throw an error.
e.g.

```
if ( 1 = c) //this will throw error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment
```

and

```
if(1 == c) //  this will work as equality condition check.
```

Comment: yoda conditions being called they are. Though, nowdays compilers warn for this and much better this is imho.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have a solution to your problem already; I had created an alternate version of your program and am just posting it here just to showcase an alternate solution.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <list>

void print_list(std::list<int> l) {
  for (auto i : l) {
    std::cout << i;
  }
  std::cout << '\n';
}

int main() {
  int length;
  std::cout << "Number: ";
  std::cin >> length;

  std::list<int> numbers{1};
  if (length == 1) {
    print_list(numbers);
    return 0;
  } else {
    print_list(numbers);  // Makes sure the "just 1" list gets printed

    for (int i = 1; i < length; ++i) {
      i & 1 ? numbers.push_front(numbers.front() ? 0 : 1)
            : numbers.push_back(numbers.back() ? 0 : 1);
      print_list(numbers);
    }
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Number: 5
1
01
010
1010
10101
```

It uses a linked list to hold the number pattern. Inside the for loop, it checks if `i` is odd, this determines whether we're adding to the front or back of the list, then each `push_` function checks if it should be pushing a `1` or `0`.

At the end of the day, I actually like your algorithm better if we only need to display the pattern. This one is good if you need to save the pattern.